# How to connect to an access point using python?

Tags: python, linux

I would create a simple program(Linux) that connects to my WIFI, is there a Wireless module in Python

Thank you

Comment: This is done by your operating system. In Python, you simply access a network device. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What has this to do with Python? This is handled on the network layer by your OS

Comment: Why an upvote for this question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is asked how to connect to a wifi network using python. There are two solutions I can think of, both with awful documentation: wicd and NetworkManager.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you really want [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/). No need to "re-invent the wheel". that's a network connection manager that works especially with wifi. It's written in Python.

Comment: try to login to my wireless access point, I do not want to re-invent the wheel, I only want to login to my wireless device.

Comment: Well then that's what you need. Along with wpa_supplicant and the right drivers.